# Android - Push Notifications gets shown on one phone only

Tags: azure, push-notification

I am using GCM with Azure Mobile Services to send push notifications.
The notifications gets sent perfectly as i can be shown on Azure Mobile Portal Logs. But the notifications get shown correctly on only one phone on which it was tested for the first time. 
I haven't set any check on it to be sent to one device only. Its an open Notifications handler and according to the code logic all devices should receive the Notifications.

Do i need to separately register each device? If yes then how.
Is there a limitation on number of devices?

Answer (score 0):

Each device need to be registered regularly, because the server remove a registration after 90 days. Generally the application is registered each it's start.

I don't how to do that on Android, but for the Mobile Services on Android you can find this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-android-get-started-push/ in particular the "Add push notifications to your app" section.

You can find the limitations depends the tiers you choose here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/

Comment: The "Application" is registered properly thats why i am getting push notifications on one phone. But can you be specific about the Registering the "Device" and how to do so. The notifications gets received on ONE phone only which also hasn't been registered.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. Apparently it's the Mobile Service SDK which register the application when you call "NotificationsManager.handleNotifications(this, SENDER_ID, MyHandler.class);". Generally I'm using directly the Notifications Hub.
Did your Other device is registered in the notificaiton hub ?

Comment: @Yanos Can you please explain how you were able to get notifications on multiple devices simultaneously? I am registering on each device, and also getting registration ID, but only one of the device gets the notification. Please help.

Comment: @Ali_Waris sorry for the delay I was in mission. Normally there is nothing to do. Each device correctly registered receive the notifications. Except if you use the tags features when sending a notification to filter devices, but I don't how it's works on Android. You can try the "Service Bus Explorer" (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a/) tool to debug your notification hub service and list the registered devices.

Comment: @Yanos Thanks for informing about the debug tool; will help me a lot for sure. There is one more question I have in mind : How to remove the registered devices from Azure? I don't see any tutorial describing how to delete the existing registered devices. Could you please throw some light on this?

Comment: @Ali_Waris non you can't remove registration from Azure. You need use the API. Look at the Service Bus Explorer, I know you can list the registrations, so I think you can delete them.

Comment: @Yanos Registrations can be deleted from Azure notifications hub. I came across this link which claims to delete registration; but I'm not able to understand it thoroughly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223268.aspx

Comment: @Ali_Waris Your link is the API Rest documentation. Yes you can delete a registration with the API, but on Azure portal you don't have interface to do it.